# Is it possible to force either Yes/No from any android Dialog?

Tags: java, android, optimization, dialog, alert

I have several intent, that
eventually asking the user whether "Yes" or "No".

In which, the dialog itself is not from my code. I just executing the Intent.

My question is quite simple.

How to surpress each dialog shown from the intent and Force it to either "yes" / "no" ?

for example this code:

```
Intent BlueIntent  = new Intent(bluetooth.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        BlueIntent.putExtra(bluetooth.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(BlueIntent);
```

We all know the above code will ask the user (by showing a YES / No dialog) to the user.
So how to force the selection programatically either "yes" or "no" for every dialog shown?

any ideas?

Comment: Can you use custom dialogs ? I'm not sure if this can be done with the default dialogs.

Comment: sure if we use custome dialog that would be possible. But how about the above statement? I mean, how could we customize it? @ShivamVerma

Comment: Have you found a solution? I think it is very valid question

Comment: I'll check it out later @Snake....

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

As much as I know this is **normally NOT** possible to override user input in another activity.

#### Reason:

You are opening the **Bluetooth Settings** using the `Intent` and let the user handle the rest. any app is not supposed to handle/alter the input events of another ***(Unless it is an accessibility service)***. So this fails the whole concept of Application security.

In case of `AccessibilityService`s the user must start them explicitly using the **Accessibility Settings** which have special services. see [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html).

An `AccessibilityService` can intercept user input and specific events but I am not sure how it can be used to achieve what you want.

**[TIP]** I think you can open the Bluetooth directly if you have the `android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permission. by this you can avoid the default dialog generated by the settings.

Hope my answer helps you.

Comment: I did already put that BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission on my project. But once I execute the above (first) code, it still asking alert Yes/No.