# Android Set Device DIscoverable (bluetooth) without any dialog

Tags: java, android, libraries

How can I set the dialog to be hidden / suppress it to Yes
when I try to execute the following code below?

```
 discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
    activity.startActivity(discoverableIntent);
```

My purpose is to enable the bluetooth discovery without asking to the user.

I don't want user choose Yes/No.  Is there any library (third party) could be used to achieve this purpose?

Comment: tool recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic]. http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED - Quoted: "Allows applications to pair bluetooth devices without user interaction. This is not available to third party applications."

Comment: @gnat: If not for the impossibility (using a software API against a restriction imposed by its provider), the question would be fit for StackOverflow as a coding question. I understand that OP has been posting a series of hacking (API circumventing) questions recently, but perhaps allow some time before closing so that others can have time to determine if this is another case of circumventing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to force either Yes/No from any android Dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606971/is-it-possible-to-force-either-yes-no-from-any-android-dialog)